# Printing a pdf as an image inside of a pdf

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, fpdf

I'm creating a web app and using a php FPDF script to creates and print out a pdf. This also prints out on the pdf images that are uploaded to the app, which is no problem. However, it needs to do the same thing for an uploaded pdf and that is where my problem lies. How can I print a pdf as an image inside of a pdf using fpdf?

I have heard of imageMagick but I don't think that is an option because it is a software and I don't know where I would run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) to import a page of an existing PDF document and place it with FPDF onto a newly created page:

```php
<?php
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

$pdf = new FPDI();

// load the document and get the total page count
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile("the/document/you/want/to/import/a/page/from.pdf");
// import the first page
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// use the imported page on x=10, y=10 and a width of 90
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 90);
// output the PDF document
$pdf->Output();
```